# Adding custom java rule to pmd maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, pmd, rule

I've wrote a custom rule for pmd (in java). I want this rule to be executed in my project. I've added my rule to pmd.xml:

```
<rule name="MyRule"
      message="some message"
      class="MyRule">
    <description>
        some description
    </description>
    <properties>
        <property name="someproperty" value="1" />
    </properties>
    <priority>3</priority>
</rule>
```

And there the problem appeared. I didn't know where to place the rule definition - MyRule.class. I was trying to add a maven dependency to pmd:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>pmd.rules</groupId>
    <artifactId>CustomJavaRules</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

where CustomJavaRules is a jar artifact (from local "file://" repo) containing MyRule.class. The jar is found and loaded but MyRule.class is still invisible for pmd.

I was trying to place the class in various directories... with poor results.

Has anyone ever had a similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>pmd.rules</groupId>
    <artifactId>CustomJavaRules</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>path/to/my/jar/CustomJavaRules.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```